# EditText isn't highlighted when touched

Tags: android, android-widget, android-edittext

I assumed this feature would be activated by default.

How do I set an EditText box to do the normal orange highlighting when a user touches it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default it is highlighted only when user clicks on it. You don't have to write anything for that.

```
<EditText
    android:layout_below="@+id/Button04" android:id="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="@+id/EditText01"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"></EditText>
```

Comment: The reason I asked is because it doesn't highlight when clicked.  It is not highlighted by default.

Comment: Oops. I had the property     android:background="@android:drawable/editbox_background" set from copying/pasting someone elses xml for an editText widget.  Making it no longer the default.. Thank you for your help